# Restart Apache after PHP update?

Tags: centos, yum, apache-httpd, php5

One of our Amazon Linux servers has php56 installed, which is not the default PHP installation. Quite often I see updates for this package, while on other server PHP is not updated.

**Do I need to restart the HTTPD service after updating php56?**

Comment: Are you using Apache's PHP module, or PHP-FPM?

Comment: We're using the Apache PHP module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to restart apache, but you need to tell it to reload its configuration.
I am not sure which command centos uses to start/stop/reload daemons.

On centos the command should be:

```
sudo service httpd graceful
```

On a linux that uses systemd the command would be:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

On debian it would be:

```
sudo apache2ctl graceful
```

Comment: I don't see a reload option. When I try `sudo apachectl reload` it displays the help info for httpd. In the end I restarted: `sudo service httpd graceful`.

Comment: thanks SPRBRN, I fixed the command accordingly :). Actually, graceful on centos should do exactly the same thing as reload on other distros